# How to export bash scripts to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I want to export this code in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

echo Starting carddav sync at $(date)

mkdir -p carddav

cat vdirsyncer.config.template | sed 
"s/VDIRSYNC_USER/$VDIRSYNC_USER/; s/VDIRSYNC_PASS/$VDIRSYNC_PASS/" > 
vdirsyncer.config

yes | vdirsyncer -c vdirsyncer.config discover

vdirsyncer -c vdirsyncer.config sync

rm vdirsyncer.config

echo Carddav sync done, starting carddavsync
```

I tried to take advantage of bash2py, but did not succeed.

Comment: You want to create equivalent code in Python?  You want to run the script from Python?  You want to...?

Comment: Unluckily SO is not a code translation service.

Comment: Please read this. [Why is "Help me" is not a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . We send people to read this, because Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use subprocess to execute bash/shell scripts in your python code. Here is an example:

```
import subprocess

command = "npm-cli-login -u "+user+" -p \""+password+"\" -e "+email+" -r \""+self.nexusUrl+"/repository/deploy.npm.cloud/\" --config-path npmrc"

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a bash script with your desired content and then execute it from within python.
Make sure to give it `execution Permissions` and possibly change the `Path` to the script if its not in the same directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
subprocess.call("./mybashscript.sh", shell=True)
```

Comment: Sorry,  but I want to rewrite the code in Python language not called by Python script

Answer (score 0):

Try importing os library and then passing the bash instructions to the function `system`, for example:

```
import os
bashCommand = 'export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8'
os.system(bashCommand)
```

Comment: Sorry,  but I want to rewrite the code in Python language not called by Python script